# How to validate or create CloudFormation stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I added CloudFormation setting files `vpc.yml` and `front.yml`, export some values in `vpc.yml` and import them.
I ran the following command, but it does not work.

```
$ aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://front.yml
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [VPCGatewayAttach] in the Resources block of the template
```

What is a valid command for the stack importing values from others?

Comment: Please post your `cft` to get a better idea of what you are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error your are getting is because you have `dependsOn` attribute in one of the resources that specifies dependency on `VPCGatewayAttach` but `VPCGatewayAttach` does not exist in your cft.

Comment: Oh, It works fine without `dependsOn` attribute!
Can we specify other stack resources as `dependsOn` using `Fn::ImportValue` or others?

Comment: No. Cannot so that.